# My SSH VPN Client Cant thruogh all trafiic to the vpn

Tags: android, android-studio

guys , i make an android app for SSH Client VPN
everything is ok with no error , but i dont know why cant dp the all trafiic of phone !
just can connect to SSH server !
Please Help Me
this is all of my body code

```
class ConfigActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_VPN = 0
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.config)

        val connectButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button6)
        connectButton.setOnClickListener {
            val username: String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextText).text.toString()
            val password: String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPassword).text.toString()
            connectToSsh(username, password)
        }
    }

    class YourVpnService : VpnService() {
        override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
            val builder = Builder()
            builder.addAddress("192.168.0.1", 24) // VPN network address
            builder.addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")       // DNS server address
            // Configure additional VPN parameters here...
            val vpnInterface = builder.establish()

            createNotificationChannel()
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getVpnNotification())

            // Handle VPN traffic...

            return START_STICKY
        }



        private fun createNotificationChannel() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "VPN Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                )
                val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
            }
        }

        private fun getVpnNotification(): Notification {
            val notificationIntent = Intent(this, ConfigActivity::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0
            )

            return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("VPN Connected")
                .setContentText("Your VPN is running.")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_secure) // Use your own icon here
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build()
        }

        companion object {
            private const val CHANNEL_ID = "VpnServiceChannel"
            private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
        }
    }

    private fun connectToSsh(username: String, password: String) {
        Thread {
            try {
                val jsch = JSch()
                val session: Session = jsch.getSession(username, "202.78.166.136", 4433)
                session.setPassword(password)
                session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
                session.connect()
                runOnUiThread {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "SSH Connected. Starting VPN...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    startVpnService()
                    session.setPortForwardingL(1080, "127.0.0.1", 1080)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                runOnUiThread {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "SSH Connection failed: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun startVpnService() {
        val intent = VpnService.prepare(this)
        if (intent != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VPN)
        } else {
            startService(Intent(this, YourVpnService::class.java))
        }
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VPN && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            startService(Intent(this, YourVpnService::class.java))
        }
    }


}
```

in this code , first you must type user and password
after that app automaticly connect to my HOST
but just connect to SSH and cant DO vpn all phone